# Service account errors when using Cloud Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

It seems like using service accounts with Dataproc is not possible because when using a service account with Cloud Dataproc I'm getting permission errors.

For example, running the command `gcloud beta dataproc clusters list` yeilds an error which says `(gcloud.beta.dataproc.clusters.list) Request had insufficient authentication scopes`

Does Cloud Dataproc allow for the use of service accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use service accounts with Cloud Dataproc.

This error is due to the requirement that the `cloud-platform` scope be enabled. The long name for this scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`.

When creating a Google Compute Engine instance it means skipping the dropdown scopes and just clicking the top-level `Allow API access to all Google Cloud services in the same project.`